# Get date to display just month and year AngularJS, Firebase

Tags: angularjs, html, date, datetime, firebase

I'm confused about how to get a date to display just a month and year using angularJS and Firebase.

I have converted a date to a string to be saved in Firebase.

Let me clarify that the date that is saved is not the current date, and is not supposed to represent the creation date of the post. It is a date that is chosen with a date picker (It is supposed to represent a past completion date of a project).

This is how the date is saved in firebase:
[image]

It is a string saved as **Mon Jan 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)**

Here is how it is displayed in the browser. This is just one "article" of many:
[image]

I'm trying to get it to display as just "**January 2016**"

I'm not sure how to get it back to a date instead of a string, and then filter it so it is just the month and the year.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="WelcomeCtrl">
        <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="article in articles">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="list-group-item active">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{article.title}}</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">Completed: {{article.date}}</p>
                <p class="list-group-item-text"><em>{{article.tech}}</em></p>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">{{article.post}}</p>

                <span class="pull-right">
                  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" ng-click="editPost(article.$id, article.date)" data-target="#editModal">EDIT</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" ng-click="confirmDelete(article.$id)" data-target="#deleteModal" >DELETE</button>
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
</body>
```

Here is my **WelcomeCtrl** controller:

```
.controller('WelcomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', 'CommonProp', function ($scope, $firebase, CommonProp) {
    $scope.username = CommonProp.getUser();
    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/articles");
    var sync = $firebase(firebaseObj);
    $scope.articles = sync.$asArray();
//I AM ASSUMING SOMETHING HAS TO GO RIGHT HERE TO CONVERT THE DATE TO A DATE OBJECT, BUT I AM NOT SURE WHAT.
//article.date = new Date(article.date); does not work.
//articles.date = new Date(articles.date); does not work.

$scope.editPost = function (id, date) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(date);

    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/articles/" + id);
    var syn = $firebase(firebaseObj);
    $scope.postToUpdate = syn.$asObject();
    $scope.postToUpdate.date = new Date(date);
    $('#editModal').modal();

};

$scope.update = function () {
    console.log($scope.postToUpdate.$id);
    var fb = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/articles/" + $scope.postToUpdate.$id);

    var article = $firebase(fb);
    article.$update({
        title: $scope.postToUpdate.title,
        tech: $scope.postToUpdate.tech,
        date: $scope.postToUpdate.date.toString(),
        post: $scope.postToUpdate.post,
        emailId: $scope.postToUpdate.emailId
    }).then(function (ref) {
        console.log(ref.key()); // bar
        $('#editModal').modal('hide');
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
    });
};


$scope.confirmDelete = function (id) {
    var fb = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/articles/" + id);
    var article = $firebase(fb);
    $scope.postToDelete = article.$asObject();
    $('#deleteModal').modal();
};

$scope.deletePost = function () {
    var fb = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/articles/" + $scope.postToDelete.$id);
    var article = $firebase(fb);
    article.$remove().then(function (ref) {
        $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error:", error);
    });
};

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string representing the date to get the number of milisconds from Jan the 1st, 1970. Then use it to create a date object, from which you can extract the number of the month (from 0 to 11) and the year.

```
var months= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var milis = Date.parse("Mon Jan 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)");
var d = new Date(milis)
console.log(months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear());
```

will display "January 2016"

So in your code it should look like this if I'm correct:

```
var months= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

for(var i=0; i<$scope.articles.length;i++) {
    var milis = Date.parse($scope.articles[i].date);
    var d = new Date(milis)
    $scope.articles[i].date = months[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: How do I access the date parameter from Firebase to get "Mon Jan 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)"? Right now I am not sure how to retrieve that.

I also have to go through a loop so that all the articles in an index (There will be many) have the date displayed properly.

Comment: I get the following error: "ReferenceError: article is not defined". This is the line causing the error: "var milis = Date.parse(article.date);"

Comment: I added the loop in my answer, it should fix it.

Comment: With your second edit that includes a loop, I do not get an error at all, however, the date is sill displayed as "Mon Jan 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)" JSHint gives a warning that "'article' is not defined".

Comment: There was a typo: I just replaced article[i] with articles[i]

Comment: Again... no error. Date is still displayed as "Mon Jan 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)". JSHint gives a warning that "'articles' is not defined". Articles plural.

Comment: I fixed it... I believe.

Comment: For some reason the For Loop is not executing. If I put a `console.log("test");` in the loop, I'm not seeing anything in the console. I've been restarting the server and refreshing with each change as well.

Comment: It didn't like the line `for(var i=0; i<$scope.articles.length; i++) {`. If I remove the `$scope.articles.length;` from the loop, and just put `i<3;` because I only have 4 entries at the moment, the loop will execute and I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined" on the first iteration. I think the Firebase id has to be there in the dot syntax before ".date".

Comment: What is in $scope.articles? Could you log it please?

Comment: If I add `console.log("$scope.articles: "+ $scope.articles);` I get nothing in the console. Nothing is output.  The actual firebase url path to the date in one of the articles is: **https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/articles/-K7S2ry_SyyE7Y9rwNOB/date** Where `-K7S2ry_SyyE7Y9rwNOB` is the id.